# Среднее значение из бесконечно поступающих данных

Tags: алгоритм, gps

Пишу программу gps навигатор, есть функция - средняя скорость.

Данные поступают постоянно и все значения записывать не вариант. У меня была идея записывать определенное количество значений, скажем, 50 и из них строить среднюю скорость.

У кого-нибудь есть предложения или может кто-то сталкивался с подобным, как вы решили проблему?

Comment: Как вариант - записывать в буфер по сотне-тысяче значений (если они приходят слишком быстро - записывать каждое энное), аппроксимировать, получать среднюю скорость с момента первого отсчета. Дальше уже вопрос того, как именно вам эти данные надо представлять - если просто одним числом без графиков, то можно прямо тут же его поправить с помощью полученного значения. Также можно постоянно писать на диск, чтобы потом считывать и обрабатывать большими кусками.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чем именно Вас не устраивает Ваша собственная идея. Вот Вы посчитали среднее по 50-ти значениям — что не так, что хотите вместо этого? Иными словами — в чём именно проблема?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, идея появилась, но я никогда не сталкивался с подобным, поэтому интересуюсь другими вариантами

Comment: См. [«Скользящее среднее»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F/) (англ. *moving average*) – простое, взвешенное, экспоненциальное.

Comment: @Sergiks по ссылке "В Википедии нет статьи с таким названием." лишний слэш в конце

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Допустим `avg` - среднее арифметическое из `n` измерений. Появляется следующее измерение `a`. Чтобы учесть это измерение достаточно пересчитать среднее `avg = avg * (n / (n + 1)) + a / (n + 1)`. Таким образом вам достаточно хранить только среднее и количество учтенных в нем измерений.

Только мне кажется, что для вашей задачи нужно будет сделать хитрый ход: ограничить выборку последними `m` - значениями. Насколько я понял, вы считаете среднюю скорость, чтобы "сгладить" резкие скачки при отображении скорости. Тогда можно принять `n` за константу ( `n = m` ) и таким образом каждый раз отбрасывать из расчета среднего измерение равное "предыдущему" среднему.

**Дополнено**

Для последнего случая необходимо получить среднее значение для начального участка. Тут можно пойти двумя путями:

1. Задать `avg` равным первому измерению;
2. Наращивать `n` от нуля до `m`.

Приведу пример:

```
double getAvg(double aNext, int m) {
  static double avg = 0;
  static double n = 0;
  avg = avg * (n / (n + 1)) + aNext / (n + 1);
  n += 1;
  if (n > m) n = m;
  return avg;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сегодня попробую это реализовать

Comment: Чтобы избежать излишних операций, достаточно хранить сумму. И количество (которое в любом случае понадобится).

Comment: @VladD Если хочется избегать излишних операций, то вообще этот фокус с ограниченным окном можно проворачивать только со сложением, вычитанием и сдвигом вправо. Только длина "выборки" должна быть степенью двух :)

Comment: В таком случае, разве средняя скорость не будет показывать слишком маленькие значения в начале пути? ( если учесть, что m=n). Или если пользователь движется очень долго с определенной скоростью, то разве в конечном итоге средняя скорость не будет превышать нормальную? Скорее всего я не совсем понял о втором варианте замены n на m

Comment: @ed8009 По поводу "начала пути" дополнил ответ. Насчет одинаковых значений в пределах выборки, они будут давать средние значения равными значениям измерений

Comment: @tutankhamun Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 3):

Средняя скорость обычно привязывается к некоторому характерному времени задачи, а данные из совсем далёкого прошлого обычно портят оценку.

В то же время есть простой способ копить данные с экспоненциальныо убывающим весом, когда рекуррентно накапливаются две суммы:

**Q' = 1 + q Q,**
**V' = v + q V.**

При этом
**v<sub>ср</sub> = V' / Q'.**

Нетрудно убедиться, что данные накапливаются с весами, представляющими собой бесконечно убывающую в сторону прошлого геометрическую прогрессию.

Выбирая **q = 1 - 1/N,** мы тем самым задаём вес **exp(-1) = 0,37** для данных, удалённых на **N** отсчётов в прошлое. При этом
**Q <= 1 / (1-q) = N,

V <= v<sub>max</sub>*N.**

Answer (score 1):

Если для GPS, разве нельзя рассчитать среднюю скорость исходя из длинны пути и прошедшего времени? т.е. Вам достаточно хранить пройденное расстояние и пройденное время от начала маршрута.